# Table list is passing wrong item to Edit Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

In ASP.NET Core I have an inline table with multiple rows on it, and I would like to edit each row independently.

```
<div class="table">
<form id="myForm">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student</th>
                <th>Grade Percent</th>
                <th>Letter Grade</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Grades)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td hidden><input type="hidden" asp-for="Grade.Id" value="@item.Id" /></td>
                    <td>@item.StudentName</td>
                    <td>@item.GradePercent</td>
                    <td>@item.Course</td>
                    <td>
                        <select asp-for="Grade.LetterGrade" class="form-control">
                            <option>@item.LetterGrade</option>
                            <option value="A">A</option>
                            <option value="B">B</option>
                            <option value="C">C</option>
                            <option value="D">D</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Grade.LetterGrade" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SaveForm('EditTest', 'Grades')">Save</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

The `view` accepts  a `ViewModel` called `Students`, which is:

```
public class Students
{
    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set;}
}
```

And `Grade` is:

```
public class Grade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public double GradePercent { get; set; }
    public char LetterGrade { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what the view looks like:
[The View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjary.png)

In my `js` file, here is `SaveForm`:

```
var SaveForm = function (Action, Controller, FormId) {
$("#loaderDiv").show();
var myformdata;
if (FormId == null) {
    $("#myForm").hide();
    myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
}
else {
    $(FormId).hide();
    myformdata = $(FormId).serialize();
}
var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.origin + "/" + Controller + "/" + Action,
    data: myformdata,
    success: function () {
        $("#loaderDiv").hide();
        //$("#myForm").show();
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
    }
});
}
```

Here is my `EditTest` method:

```
public IActionResult EditTest(int id)
{
    var grade = _context.Grades.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    Students g = new Students { Grade = grade };
    return View(g);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditTest(Students gra)
{
    var g = _context.Grades.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == gra.Grade.Id);
    g.LetterGrade = gra.Grade.LetterGrade;
    _context.Update(g);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(true);
}
```

Whenever I hit the Save button, I debug and watch it and for example if the two objects have `@item.Id` equal to 4 and 7 respectively, no matter which one I try to edit, it will only send `Id` equals 4 to the controller. So only the first `item` gets edited.

I have searched and tried many different approaches, but I am wondering if this code puts me on the right track,  or I need something completely different?

This is the `myformdata` after trying to set `@item.Id == 4` to `LetterGrade == 'B'`:

```
"Grade.Id=3&Grade.LetterGrade=B"
```

Comment: Your question lacks an important information. Where is the javascript code executed in the SaveForm function?  Also I would also add the code in the PageModel that responds to the SaveForm call.

Comment: okay I will add the information.

Comment: Looking at the image posted is seems that you have two identical items displayed. Perhaps the problem is in the Get part that prepare the Model.Grades list.

Comment: No my apologies, for testing purposes I created multiples with very similar data, they are indeed different items, I will edit the image too, just to be more clear.

Comment: If you press the F12 key and look at the row elements do you see different values in the  td for "Grade.Id" ?

Comment: Yes, the values are different, I even changed the values in the database manually, and changed the picture to show that the values are different, the Id are 3 and 4

Comment: I can only suppose that the JQuery.serialize function serializes the whole form, not only the clicked row. So the net core deserialization builds only the first object. Could you print on the console the value serialized _myformdata_?

Comment: Okay I added more.

Comment: It appears what you're posting is not a match for what the controller method is actually accepting.

Comment: I have made more edits, I think now the post should be clear and make sense, I have added my `Model` and `ViewModel` that I am using in the view as well as in my edit action.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you can delete `<form id="myForm">`,and use form in each row,change `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SaveForm('EditTest', 'Grades')">Save</a>` to `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>`,and each time you click save button,post your row data to controller action with form,and then you don't need to use ajax to post data,here is a demo worked:

EditTest.cshtml:

```
<div class="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student</th>
                    <th>Grade Percent</th>
                    <th>Letter Grade</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Grades)
                {
                <form method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td hidden><input type="hidden" asp-for="Grade.Id" value="@item.Id" /></td>
                        <td>@item.StudentName</td>
                        <td>@item.GradePercent</td>
                        <td>@item.Course</td>
                        <td>
                            <select asp-for="Grade.LetterGrade" class="form-control">
                                <option value="@item.LetterGrade">@item.LetterGrade</option>
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                <option value="C">C</option>
                                <option value="D">D</option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Grade.LetterGrade" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult EditTest(int id)
        {
            List<Grade> grades = new List<Grade> { new Grade { Id = 1, Course = "English", LetterGrade = 'x', GradePercent = 12.2, StudentName = "S" }, new Grade { Id = 2, Course = "Maths", LetterGrade = 'l', GradePercent = 52.2, StudentName = "J" } };
            Students g = new Students {Grades=grades, Grade = new Grade {  Id=1, Course= "English", LetterGrade='x', GradePercent=12.2, StudentName="S"} };
            return View(g);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditTest(Students gra)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EditTest", new { id = gra.Grade.Id });
        }
```

result:
[image]